# Format interval date type as a parameter in PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

What is the best way to parameterize interval date type in a PostgreSQL function?. I have the following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(
min_time integer
) 
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE foo AS
 SELECT
     gid,
     now() + concat(%s, ' hours')::interval as x,

  FROM foobar
  limit 3  ',min_time  );

 END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Each time I try to execute the function I get the following error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "hours"`

Comment: You are not nesting strings correctly. Single quotes embedded in a string constant need to be escaped by doubling them. `concat(%s, '' hours'')::interval` - but using `make_interval()` would probably be a lot easier

Comment: Why use dynamic SQL at all? This seems pretty pointless in this case

Comment: This is just a dummy example. I have my use case of using dynamic SQL because I need to use it in different context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes have to be escaped in a string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(min_time integer) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'CREATE TABLE foo AS
               SELECT gid,
                      now() + ''%s hours''::interval as x
               FROM foobar
               limit 3',
              min_time
           );
END;
$BODY$;
```

But actually, you don't need dynamic SQL for that, and static SQL might be the better choice:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing(min_time integer) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   CREATE TABLE foo (
      gid bigint NOT NULL,
      x timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
   );

   INSERT INTO foo
   SELECT gid,
          now() + min_time * '1 hour'::interval
   FROM foobar
   limit 3;
END;
$BODY$;
```